# How can I use "for" loop and "if" loop both together to verify the existence of xml elements in xml document

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to make a login system. For that I need to check existence of xml elements ("username" and "password") in xml document. If match the "username" and "password" need to return true, otherwise false. For that I use "for" loop to go through the entire document and use "if" loop for validation. I'm using java and dom parser.

xml document:

```
<login>
<user>
    <username>sunimal</username>
    <password>1111</password>
</user>
<user>
    <username>naveen</username>
    <password>852</password>
</user>
<user>
    <username>chamara</username>
    <password>12345</password>
</user></login>
```

java code:

```
boolean a = false;
    try {
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Kavindu\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\chatserver2\\xml\\userrecord2.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory
                = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);

        NodeList userList = doc.getElementsByTagName("login");

          for (int i = 0; i < userList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node user = userList.item(i);
            Element eElement = (Element) user;

            if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("username").item(i).getTextContent().equals(username) && eElement.getElementsByTagName("password").item(i).getTextContent().equals(password)) {

                a = true;
            } else {
                a = false;
            }
        }




    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return a;
}
```

If I input first elements("sunimal" and "1111"),I can get true, but for other elements return false. I tried "for" loop and "if" loop in different ways, but I couldn't get the result.I'm newly with programming.

Comment: if there exist another way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution; I have checked this in my IDE. Thanks. :-)

to get the first element of a tag you need to use index 0.  `eElement.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0)`

When you have matched user name and password you need to get out from the loop,

a = true;
  break;

otherwise in the next iteration it will set to false again.

```
public boolean checkLogin(){

boolean a = false;
try {
    File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Kavindu\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\chatserver2\\xml\\userrecord2.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory
            = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    NodeList userList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
    System.out.println("userlist length :: "+ userList.getLength());
      for (int i = 0; i < userList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node user = userList.item(i);
        Element eElement = (Element) user;
        if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0).getTextContent().equals(username) && eElement.getElementsByTagName("password").item(0).getTextContent().equals(password)) {

            a = true;
            break;
        } else {
            a = false;
        }
    }




} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

}
return a;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
NodeList userList = doc.getElementsByTagName("login");
```

returns a single node, the root node (`<login>`).  What you want is

```
NodeList userList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
```

This will return a `NodeList` containing one element per user, and then your for loop will iterate over the users.

Then in

```
if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("username").item(i).getTextContent().equals(username) 
        && 
    eElement.getElementsByTagName("password").item(i).getTextContent().equals(password)) { ...
```

Change the `item(i)` to `item(1)`.  At that point you are "at" the `<user>` element so the username and password are the "first" nodes of that type.

Comment: As you said i changed it. but it still gives same result, and also i changed for loop "i < userList.getLength()" to "i< 3" (because of three users), but it gives same result.

Comment: See my update.  Also, please study how to use your IDE debugger to step through your code and examine variables.  It will allow you to solve problems like this on your own.